# ASP.NET MVC, create View method that would return multiple objects to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to create a View() method that would return multiple objects, for example, I would like to call it something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View(CustomObject1 customObject1, CustomObject2 customObject2);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Well, I was doing some custom override for RazorViewEngine, and this came to my mind, so I wanted to see if this is possible, and to see how..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just create a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public CustomObject1 CustomObject1 { get; set; }
    public CustomObject2 CustomObject2 { get; set; }
}
```

which you will pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.CustomObject1 = customObject1;
    model.CustomObject2 = customObject2;
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally make your view strongly typed to this view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and access the corresponding properties when needed:

```
 <div>@Model.CustomObject1.FoorBar</div>
```