# How can I return users and roles in the same View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning asp.net core MVC and I am trying to just make a simple user management model, but I cant seem to figure out how to make an algorithm that outputs the user and their role. I believe its due to the function outputting the user as a string, and the roles being output as a List. I cant seem to successfully call two model to make  the Model work. Or am I doing this incorrectly?

I can get it to successfully list the user and their info with this

```
        [Route("EditUser/{id?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }
  

            return View(user);
}
```

However since I have 3 or 4 different roles I cant just use List<>  right?

```
        var model = new List<ManageUserRolesViewModel>();

        foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles)
        {
            var userRolesViewModel = new ManageUserRolesViewModel
            {
                RoleId = role.Id,
                RoleName = role.Name
            };
            if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
            {
                userRolesViewModel.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                userRolesViewModel.Selected = false;
            }
            model.Add(userRolesViewModel);
        }
```

Which I cant output to view due to the string vs list issue.

```
<div class="card-body">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].RoleId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].RoleName" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].Selected">
                        @Model[i].RoleName
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Read up about viewmodel objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC, create View method that would return multiple objects to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510519/asp-net-mvc-create-view-method-that-would-return-multiple-objects-to-the-view)

Comment: No that returns an error message about the ApplicationUser Dictionary not matching List<UserRolesViewModels>.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to that
1)You can store user data into Sessions and as per need, you can read at the view page.

```
Session["User"]=Users; // list of user or single logged user with role
```

2. Make a common model or class with user data and view data.

**The ViewModel**

> ```
> public class UserDetailsViewModel
> {
>     public string UserName { get; set; }
>     public string UserRole { get; set; }
> }
> ```

**The Action Method**

```
[Route("EditUser/{id?}")] 
 public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id) {   //Your Logic

    var viewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel();
    viewModel.UserName = "UserName";
    viewModel.UserRole = "UserRole";
    return View(viewModel); 
 }
```

**The View (Razor)**

```
@model UserDetailsViewModel

// use Model.UserName and Model.UserRole
```

Comment: So you can directly call a view in a model? I did not know that. That makes much more sense.

Comment: No, In the case of session you fill session at controller side and at view side you can read it.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. Let me work on that.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. That will help you.

Comment: Itll take a while. It doesnt like the code either. Its not wanting me to loop through the roles and see which one the user is in for the view. Doesnt seem to be joining a List and a string... Ill give it a few but likely about to just give up all together.

Comment: Definitely doesnt work. When I do it like this the form loads, but the values are blank. When I follow the comment example above or which is similar to this https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/view-model-asp-net-core-mvc/ Everything turns red and wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

It's no need to pass the user or role's model to the view directly, You can just  pass their `string` Names.

In this demo, I will only show that one user corresponds to multiple roles, Other correspondences are basically the same as this.

*I create a ViewModel contains user and role's name*

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserRoleModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public List<string> RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller, I will return `List<UserRoleModel>`

**controller**

```
public IActionResult Show()
        {
            //get the User and Role from database and add them to UserRoleModel.
           //I'm assuming you got the User (jack and mike) and their corresponding roles
  
            List<UserRoleModel> userRoleModel = new List<UserRoleModel>
            {
                 new UserRoleModel
                 {
                    UserName = "Jack",
                    RoleName = new List<string> {
                        "Admin",
                        "User",
                        "Other"
                    }
                 },

                new UserRoleModel()
                {
                    UserName = "Mike",
                    RoleName = new List<string> {
                        "Admin",
                        "User",
                        "Other"
                    }
                }
            };
            return View(userRoleModel);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model List<CustomIdentity.Models.UserRoleModel>

<h1>User and Roles</h1>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    <div>User: @item.UserName</div>
    @foreach (var role in item.RoleName)
   {
       <div>Role: @role</div>
   }
   <br />
}
```

**Then you can get the user and roles in the same view**

[image]